# How to set Consumer started once and goes on forever uninterruptedly.

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I am very new to RabbitMQ and using RabbitMQ 3.5.3, Erlang R14B04, and a  library by Alvaro Videla(https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib) for queuing in RabbitMQ. 
I need to keep my consumers conection alive all the time not the producer.
**The simple logic behind this is, I am running my producer through cron. As after the queue is getting generated there is no need to keep producer connection alive. But the worker or consumer will be initiated once. And this connection should never die.**

If this is also done by cron I always end up with a long list of consumer connections at the end of the day, which is annoying, and not desirable.

So the punchline here is:

**1. Produce the queue and close the connection by cron every time.**

**2. Consumer started once and goes on forever. Anything queued will be consumed instantly.**

Can this architecture be built in my system. What necessary changes I need to make here.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your description is hard to say something more or I just don't understand your problem well. But I would built app what is checking rabbit every 1 second or 3 seconds if something arrive

Consumer

```
createConnectionToRabbit
while (true) {
  checkConnectionStillAlive
  fetchDataFromQueue
  doProcessData
  sleep(3)
}
closeConnection
```

Producer

```
createConnectionToRabbit
sendDataToRabbit
closeConnection
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually Last Friday I created a connection of worker & made it as TCP keep alive-on and heartbeat-30s and let my system running for the weekend. Monday I found this alive, everything is working fine.  I got the connection, the channel, the blank queue all alive. But as soon as I queued two messages, everything except the queue were gone all of a sudden. I get the hike in the graph for two messages. Was this connection actually alive? If yes, what happened to them while queuing? How to stop this behavior. I need to get the messages to be consumed always after any which idle time.